# How to handle incremented values from the bottom of a page for operations at the top of the same page

Tags: php

I've configured "paginating" for a site I'm working on whereby 4 posts are rendered per page.  Works fine.  Now I would like to set up links at the top of the page so that, depending on the number of posts on the page, the links change.

1) If you're on the first page and their are less than 4 posts, the "previous" and "next" links are greyed out.

2) If you're on the first page and there are 4 posts, but there are ONLY four posts to render total, then "previous" and "next" links are greyed out.

3) If you're on the first page and there are 4 posts, but there are more posts to render, "previous" is greyed out, "next" is a clickable link taking you to the next page

Typical logic.  The trick is that if you're on the last page of results, and there ARE more posts, both links should be clickable.  If there aren't, than "next" should be greyed out.  Also, if there are less than 4 posts on a page, but you're not on page 1, than "previous" should be clickable, but "next" should be greyed out.

So, I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle this.  My page of rendered posts has an incrementing function that counts posts ($countposts), but it's at the bottom of the page and the value is needed at the top of the page to determine the condition to apply.  Am I thinking about this the right way, or is there something much easier I could be doing?

Comment: _"The trick is that if you're on the last page of results, and there ARE more posts, both links should be clickable."_ If there are are more posts, then you're not on the last page. Try Googling PHP pagination class. There are a million to pick from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (often used) solution is output buffering (http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php):

```
<?php
ob_start();
// All output will be buffered

$count = 0;
while($post = get_post()) { // or something lik that
    $count++;
    ?>
     <h2><?= $post->title ?></h2>
    <?
}

$content = ob_get_clean(); // Turn off buffering and store output in $content

// Generate navigation here
if ($count < 4) {
    echo "No navigation";
}

// Echo the content from the buffer
echo $content
```

Comment: This totally did the trick, but I've uploaded the other suggestions as well.  Thanks, Peter.